# i can't pass from 1.6 to 2.3.3 for Andengine

Tags: android, 2d, andengine

i have a book which is called "Learning Android Game Programming-Rick Rogers".But their examples are writting for android 1.6.So i can't run their codes for android 2.3.3. When i try to run for 2.3.3, it creates an error(force close)..i use eclipse for java.What can i do?

Comment: All code should be compatible. You just can run apps with a higher API than the phone your using.

Comment: would be great if you could provide this sample code

Answer (score 0):

it would be nice if you could post your logcat from Eclipse, note that codes made for older versions of Android may be using deprecated/non existing methods in newer but there are always equivalent methods. :)